# change UIBarbuttonitem font in the UINavigationbar of a mailcomposer

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I'm calling `UIActivitycontroller` with UIActivityTypeMail which opens a mailcomposer with it's own `UINavigationbar`. I would like to change the font of the `UIBarbuttonitems` in that UinavigationBar. 
I've already tried:

```
[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes
```

and

```
[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitletextAttributes
```

it works fine for the Navigationbar of the `UIImagepicker` but the mail `UIBarbuttons` seems to ignore both lines. Any Hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: when are you setting them ?

Comment: in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but like I said it works fine everywhere else just the Viewcontroller openend with UIActivityController seems to ignore it.